# Process name 'masked' by /usr/bin/python and /bin/su

Tags: python, process-management, pidof

I'm trying to use the `pidof` command to see my script is already running as I only want this executable if the script is not already running, however, it seems the `pidof` command is not returning the *pid* of the script using the name which is displayed in `ps -ef` output. Instead it is masking this name as either `/usr/bin/python` or `/bin/su`. Can someone shed some light on what is going on and how I can run `pidof 'script.py -v'` to see if the script is running or not?

```
[root@cloud proc]# pidof python /some/dir/script.py -v
> pidof: invalid options on command line!

[root@cloud proc]# pidof "python /some/dir/script.py -v"
>

[root@cloud proc]# pidof "su - user -c python /some/dir/script.py -v"
> 

[root@cloud proc]# ps -ef | grep script.py
> root      5409 31739  0 13:07 pts/1    00:00:00 su - user -c python /some/dir/script.py -v
> user      5414  5409 96 13:07 ?        01:00:40 python /some/dir/script.py -v

[root@cloud proc]# ls -l /proc/5409/exe
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Oct 13 14:04 /proc/5409/exe -> /bin/su

[root@cloud proc]# ls -l /proc/5414/exe
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 0 Oct 13 14:04 /proc/5414/exe -> /usr/bin/python

[root@cloud proc]# pidof /bin/su
> 31715 6308 5409

[root@cloud proc]# pidof /usr/bin/python
> 5414
```

Comment: Can you use `pgrep`? Then you could do `pgrep -f '/some/dir/script.py -v'`

Comment: I've found a cleaner Python solution, however, pgrep did in fact work. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The mystery of the masking is, however, still unsolved.!

Comment: Does your cleaner Python solution involve locking? I was thinking about suggesting that, but didn't want to stray too far from the basic question that you asked.

Comment: It does indeed. I've went with a similar implementation to the one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337488/bash-locking-mechanism-using-sockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pidof` doesn't offer a way to specify `/path/to/script` to match commands of the form `interpretername /path/to/script`. It always looks at the *filename of the executable* listed in the `/proc/pid/stat` file.

But it will work if your script begins with a *shebang* `#!` and if you invoke the script with `/path/to/script`.

As an alternative, most GNU/Linux systems offer a `pgrep` command, which can match all or part of a command line. In your example, you can use

```
pgrep -x -f 'python /some/dir/script.py -v'
```

This will match the exact command line. If you want to match a partial command line, you can do something like

```
pgrep -x -f 'python /some/dir/script.py .*'
```

You can omit the `-x` to put an implicit `.*` at the beginning and end of the pattern, but this will also match your `su - user -c python /some/dir/script.py -v` process.

As you mentioned in comments, a better way to assure your command doesn't run multiple instances at the same time is to use file locking, such as [fcntl.flock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html).